# change button color when we click on it in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, button, click

I seen the multiple thread on stackoverflow related the same title of this post but this different which I am going to ask.
I am trying to make code in jQuery that suppose my default button color is `gray` and I wish I click one time It will convert to `green` and when I click `twice` on btn or `click` green btn again it will becomes `red`.
overall when I single click on btn it will `green` and when I click `double` it will `red` and when I click `third` it will default color as `grey` **OR** when I click `green` it will `red` and when click `red` it will `grey`

I want to post this btn data when If btn is `grey` then btn value = 0 same when `green` == 1 and when `red` == 3

I tried to make code but I only know single click function without btn value..
Please help me to creating this code..

```js
jQuery("#my_styles .btn").click(function() {
  jQuery("#my_styles .btn").removeClass('active');
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
    background:red;
}
button.btn:active{
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML--
<div class="col-sm-12" id="my_styles">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="1" value="0">Button1</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="2" value="0">Button2</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12" id="my_styles">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="3" value="0">Button3</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="4" value="0">Button4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Create two classes `btn-red` and `btn-green`. You already have a value attribute on your button. Update the value to `currentValue+1` each time the button is clicked. Based on the value `0 = no class`, `1 = btn-green` and `2 = btn-red`. After the value is greater than 2 reset it to 0. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use value for change color and val();

See this example:

```js
jQuery("#my_styles .btn").click(function() {
  var button=jQuery(this).val();
  if(button==1){
  jQuery(this).removeClass('activegreen');
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('activered');
  jQuery(this).val('3');
  }else if(button==0){
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('activegreen');
  jQuery(this).val('1');
  }else{
  jQuery(this).removeClass('activered');
  jQuery(this).val('0');
  }
  });
jQuery("#reset").click(function() {   
  jQuery('#my_styles .btn').val('0');
  jQuery('#my_styles .btn').removeClass('activered');
  jQuery('#my_styles .btn').removeClass('activegreen');
  
});
```

```css
button.btn{
background:grey;
}
.activered{
    background:red!important;
}

.activegreen{
    background:green!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML--
<div class="col-sm-12" id="my_styles">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="1" value="0">Button1</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="2" value="0">Button2</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12" id="my_styles">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="3" value="0">Button3</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="4" value="0">Button4</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12" id="my_styles">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="reset" value="4">Reset</button>

</div>
```

So now when you click one time will be `green` with `val=1`, if click again will be `red` with `val=3` when click again will be `grey` with `val=0`

Comment: Thank You master .. but how I add reset btn ..? when I click on that all value will 0 and btn will default color.. ?

Comment: you are awesome

Comment: one last thing pls tell me Mr. Simone Rossaini : suppose I have one btn[selectALL] When I click select all When I click deselect all When I click 3rd time it will normal with value changes.. How I achieve ? [selectAll] [deselectAll] [resetAll] the btn will one btn text and function will change.. Could you help me last time agian...

Comment: please create a new question i will see

Comment: this is small sir please help

Comment: i will don't worry, create a new question

Answer (score 2):

You can check the class and change the color that way. Let me know if I didn't understand your issue correctly :)

**JavaScript**

```
$( '#myButton' ).click( function() {
  this.isGreen = $( '#myButton' ).hasClass( 'green' );
  this.isGray = $( '#myButton' ).hasClass( 'gray' );
  this.isRed = $( '#myButton' ).hasClass( 'red' );
  
  if ( this.isGray ) {
      $( '#myButton' ).removeClass( 'gray' ).addClass( 'green' );
      this.value = 1;
  }
  else if ( this.isGreen ) {
      $( '#myButton' ).removeClass( 'green' ).addClass( 'red' );
      this.value = 2;
  }
  else if ( this.isRed ) {
      $( '#myButton' ).removeClass( 'red' ).addClass( 'gray' );
      this.value = 0;
  }
  
  console.log( this.value ); // do whatever you want with the value
} );
```

**CSS**

```
#myButton.green {
  background: green;
}

#myButton.gray {
  background: gray;
}

#myButton.red {
  background: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="myButton" class="gray" value="0">
  Sample
</button>
```

Comment: click one separate btn when click on that select all btn as green  and again click on same btn will red how ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand what you're trying to ask..

Answer (score 1):

```js
var clickCount = 0;
$("#my_styles .btn").click(function() {
  clickCount++;
  console.log(clickCount);
  if(clickCount % 2 == 0 ) {
    $(this).addClass('red');
  }else {
  $(this).removeClass('red');
  $(this).toggleClass('green');
  }
});

$("#my_styles .btn").dblclick(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('green');
  $(this).toggleClass('red');
});
```

```css
.green{
   background:green;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12" id="my_styles">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="1" value="0">Button1</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="2" value="0">Button2</button>
</div>
```

Check this code. It will somewhat help you. But your approach will cause problem later. So, I would recommend to change your approach a little bit. Don't use double click and click functionality for same button it would cause problem.